# Plot absolute error vs step-size as a log-log plot (MATLAB)

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have approximated up to $t=2$ with step sizes $h=(1/2)^{n}$ for $n=1, ... , 10$ using a Runge-Kutta (order 4) MATLAB code. Then, I wrote down the absolute error of $y(2)$. Now, I want to plot the log(error) against the log(h), in MATLAB.

I should get a line with slope 4 (I think), because the Runge-Kutta method has order 4 and because $error\approx C(h^{k})$ and so $\log(error)=\log(C)+k\log(h)$, where $k$ is the order of the numerical method. I've tried this several different ways by searching the internet, but nothing seems to be correct. Most recently, I've tried to define a vector $xval$ containing the $h$ step sizes and a vector 
 $yval$ containing the errors. Then I used $loglog(x, y, '-s')$ to obtain a graph, but when I used $polyfit(xval, yval, 1)$, I did not get back a slope of 4.

I'm really confused about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my data (step size, error):
\begin{align*}
&1/2, \qquad 6.99e^{-2}\\ 
 &1/4 \qquad 1.08e^{-2}\\ 
 &1/8 \qquad 1.02e^{-3}\\ 
 &1/16 \qquad 7.2e^{-5}\\ 
 &1/32 \qquad 4.54e^{-6}\\ 
 &1/64 \qquad 2.78e^{-7}\\ 
 &1/128 \qquad 1.71e^{-8}\\ 
 &1/256 \qquad 1.06e^{-9}\\ 
 &1/512 \qquad 6.57e^{-11}\\ 
 &1/1024 \qquad 4.11e^{-12}\\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: If you insist on using `poly fit` you should be fitting `log(h)` and `log(error)` not `h` and `error`.

Comment: Right... unfortunately I don't have MATLAB available to me at the moment so I will try this later. Hopefully that yields the slope of 4, I don't know what else the problem could be.

Comment: I just tried this, and it returned a slope of 1.65. Is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: There are lots of things that could be wrong if you have coded it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using R and obtain

```
## define new variables:
log_h   = log(h),
log_err = log(err)

## perform a linear fit:
lm(formula = log_err ~ log_h, data = df)

## display the summary of fit:
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.76940 -0.13870  0.04283  0.25340  0.37336 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.78235    0.24929   3.138   0.0138 *  
log_h        3.85725    0.05796  66.546 2.89e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3649 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9982,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.998 
F-statistic:  4428 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 2.893e-12
```

So the estimated slope is $3.85 \pm 0.05$, which is pretty close to 4. The plot shows a straight line. The residuals are OK -- not shown here.

[image]

In Matlab one would do something like

```
p = polyfit(log_h, log_err, 1)
```

Comment: I tried to do this on SAS, but I got an error saying that my data was invalid. Did you input the data as $(x, y)$ and then define a new variable to be the log of each coordinate? Does that make sense? I'm not sure how R works..

Comment: I did it the "stupid" way and defined new variables. Of course you don't have to do this.

Comment: On MATLAB I tried polyfit(log(xval), log(yval), 1) and got a slope of about 1.7. Any ideas?

Comment: You obviously have a typo in your code. If I have typos, I usually go step by step through the code and cross check is. Since you expect a straight line the debugging should be rather simple.

Comment: well if you got a slope of close to 4 using my data, it seems that my code calculates the errors correctly. I've double checked and can't find any typos with the way I enter my vector of step sizes and my vector of error values. No idea what's wrong..